# Get matched expression inside match block

Tags: rust, switch-statement

Is it possible to access the matched expression inside a match block?

Considering this example, with what should I replace `HERE`?

```
fn fetch_u32(args: &mut Vec<&str>) -> Result<u32,String> {
    match args.remove(0).parse::<u32>() {
        Ok(result) => Ok(result),
        Err(_) => Err("Argument '" + HERE + "' is not of type uint32".to_string())
    };
}
```

Comment: Do you _really_ want the expression matched (`args.remove(0).parse::<u32>()`), or just the `args.remove(0)` part? The `Err` portion suggests the latter, but the rest of the question suggest the former.

Comment: @E_net4: The latter. Sorry for the misleading question.

Comment: 1) As hinted in the answer given, the trick is indeed to bind the unparsed argument into its own variable. Personally I'd not even use `match` when an error mapping suffices: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=259a34067473064c10727df15884257e

Comment: 2) A [`VecDeque`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.VecDeque.html) might be more suitable if removing elements from the front is a common operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply extract the expression before, and reuse the binding in the error message.

```rust
fn fetch_u32(args: &mut Vec<&str>) -> Result<u32, String> {
    let a = args.remove(0);
    match a.parse::<u32>() {
        Ok(result) => Ok(result),
        Err(_) => Err(format!("Argument '{}' is not of type uint32", a)),
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut args = vec!["123", "bla", "456", "hop"];
    while !args.is_empty() {
        let r = fetch_u32(&mut args);
        println!("{:?}", r);
    }
}
/*
Ok(123)
Err("Argument 'bla' is not of type uint32")
Ok(456)
Err("Argument 'hop' is not of type uint32")
*/
```

Comment: Works for me, although I must admit, I like the alternative using `map_err` suggested by E_net4 better.

Comment: @Twonky Yes, I also prefer the `map_err` alternative, but I wanted to stay as close as possible to your original code.